# iphone update some files in application

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, replace, download

I'm creating one iphone application that uses and xml to get some data from and a few images. Lets say that originally these files will be in the application bundle. But then I want to make my application to get updates from a web service. So lets say I download a new xml and new Images.

Where do I save them? I think I will be able to save them in the application "cache" right?

But then How do I make my application check if this resource exists in the cache, then load that one...else load the one in the application bundle?

iOS to be used 4.3 but if it makes it easier we can go to 5.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use NSFileManager to save the file to and load it from the document directory. Check out the following link, which actually contains all the info you need:

http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/02/using-nsfilemanager-to-save-an-image-to-or-loadremove-an-image-from-documents-directory-coding/

If `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];` (fullPath being the NSString with contains the path to your image in your document directory) returns nil, then the image is not present, so you'll have to load the default image from your bundle.

You can access your default bundle files using [`[NSBundle mainbundle] pathForResource:@"yourFileNameHere" ofType:@"yourTypeHere"]` This will return the path to your file in your bundle and you can just pass it to `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`

This example only applies to UIImage, but you can easily adapt it to use other classes. I think the UIImage example is enough for illustrative purposes though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to create a versioning scheme.  After the app starts (or periodically) call the web service for a very cheap call to ask what version it has.  You'll know what version you have (write in a plist or have the version number in the folder structure).  Another options is [pushing a notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

The next thing you'll have to think about is how the app reacts to getting a new data set.  You could do it only on start up but that might block the start up experience if you're bounding it to a web call.  The other option is to allow the dataset to change while the app is open.  You could have a model that uses [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to notify your views and controllers that the data has changed.  I would probably version the storage as well (folder per) to help with the transition.

As for how, you can make web requests with something like [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to write to the documents directory, and [plists](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) to save settings like version.